# How to mock @viewchild in angular test case

Tags: angular, mocking, viewchild

I am trying to mock viewchild in my angular test cases. I tried to use fixture.componentInstance, it doesn't work.
How to mock @ViewChild in angular 4 test cases.

```
export class AA{
@ViewChild('view') testView;
}
```

Comment: Can you be more clear? How does your template and components look like? And what are you testing?

Comment: What is `view`? Is it a template reference, component or directive?